# Weil Divisors of Elliptic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Take any elliptic curve over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ . If you fix a collection of affine rational points on the curve $P_1,...P_n$, there is a differential $\omega$ such that $\mathcal{v}_{P_i}(\omega)=-1$ and $\omega_{P_i}(1)=1$. My goal is to "find" such a differential for specific cases.

There is a one to one correspondence between functions on the curve and Weil differentials. Is there a natural way of constructing a function $f$ such that $df$ has the properties above.

There is no important reason for specifying an elliptic curve but I thought it may be the easiest place to start.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+\tau\mathbb{Z})$ should be easier to visualize, the meromorphic differentials are of the form $f(z)dz$ with $f \in \mathbb{C}(\wp(z),\wp'(z))$ and $div(f) = \sum_j [q_j]-[p_j],\sum_j q_j -p_j \in \mathbb{Z}+\tau\mathbb{Z}$